# How can I approve an association between a chrome app and a domain?

Tags: google-search-console, chrome-web-store

I am trying to associate a new domain with my chrome app.  I've tried uploading the new manifest file, but the Web Store dashboard says:

> This hosted web app specifies one or more URLs that are not matched by sites you own. If this app will be published for anyone to access, you must verify ownership of or association to sites to match all of the URLs listed below.
>
> Unmatched app urls:
>   https://www.mydomain.com/
>   To verify your ownership of these websites, add the necessary websites using Google Webmaster Tools and return here to complete this step.
>
> If the site already has an owner, you may request they grant you an association which allows you to publish apps and extensions to the Chrome Web Store on behalf of the site. You may request an association in the verified website section below.

In Google Webmaster Tools, I see the following message:

> https://www.mydomain.com/: Chrome Web Store associate request received
>   March 21, 2014
>
> You requested permissions to publish apps and extensions to the Chrome
>   Web Store on behalf of https://www.mydomain.com/. You will receive a
>   message telling you when your request has been approved.

In the verified website section, I see:

> https://www.mydomain.com/: The association request placed 3/21/14 11:51 AM is pending action by the site's owner. If you know who the owner is, you should contact them and ask them to approve it for you. If you don't, there is nothing else you can do to make this happen more quickly.

What do I need to do in order to get this association approved?  The Web Store makes it sound like I need to do something in Google Webmaster Tools, but Google Webmaster Tools makes it sound like there's nothing to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by specifying `https://mydomain.com` rather than `https://www.mydomain.com`.